# Is there a calculi that is correct but not complete?

Tags: logic

I`ve to find a calculi that is complete but not correct and one that is correct but not complete.

complete, not correct:

$K=\{R\}\quad  \emptyset\vDash F \,\Rightarrow \, \emptyset\vdash F  $

because you can derived every rule from $\emptyset\vdash$.
But if you have derived a rule from $\emptyset\vdash$ it doesn`t have to be a tautology (example F=A⋅B), so it is not correct.

Do you know an example, where the Calculi is correct but not complete?

$K=\{R\}\quad  M\vdash F \,\Rightarrow \, M\vDash F  $

means: if you can derived F from M ($\vdash$ with rule R), than F is a logical consequence of M.

$K=\{R\}\quad  M\vDash F \,\Rightarrow \, M\vdash F  $

means: K is complete, if F is a logical consequence of M, then F can be derived from M.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I think you are going to need to say a bit more about your (rather unusual) notation to get a useful answer to this. E.g., tell us what textbook you are using.

Comment: Just take a system with no rules of inference at all. Trivially correct, trivially not complete.

Comment: 'Calculi' is plural; 'calculus' is the singular.  Think cactus-cacti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume $K$ is set of rules of inference.

If $K$ is set of *all* rules of your calculus, then the answer is yes. Take $K = \emptyset$ (empty set). Everything derivable is true, because nothing but axioms is derivable. But you can't derive any theorem that's not an axiom; thus the system is incomplete. (I assume you're using a calculus that doesn't already include all theorems as axioms; in that case, rules of inference are superfluous)

If $K$ is set of *additional* rules of your (already complete) calculus, then the answer is no. Additional rules don't change the set of what was provable prior to changes, and this prior system could already prove all the truths.